# get day of the week from the date column containing multiple dates inside a list and add multiples of 48 to a new column created

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a data frame similar to the one below.

**Code for input dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'date':[['2022-1-12'],'NA',['2022-02-26, 2022-02-19'],'NA',['2022-02-20, 2022-02-27']],
                   'slots':[[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],'NA',[[14, 15, 16, 17], [14, 15, 16, 17,18]],'NA',[[14, 15, 16, 17], [14, 15, 16, 17,18]]]
                  })
```

**Output**
[input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htSim.png)

As we can see, It contains a date column(date) which has a list of dates and a slots column containing multiple lists consisting of multiple slot numbers (eg 14, 15, 16, etc)

**I wanted to do two tasks,**

**1)**
create a new column "day",  which is the day of the week of the respective "date" column

**example:**

```
          date                         day
['2022-05-25, 2022-05-26']    ['Wednesday, Thursday']

['2022-06-25, 2022-06-26']    ['Saturday, Sunday']
```

**2)**

If the day name inside the day column is Monday, then whatever the values  present in the list respective to that day(Monday) will be as is.

If the day name inside the day column is Tuesday, then 48*1+slot_value respective to the day(Tuesday)

Similarly,

If the day name inside the day column is Sunday, then 48*6+slot_value respective to the day(Sunday)

Please refer below Monday to Sunday table for reference

**NOTE**

```
Monday    slot_value inside slots column
Tuesday   48*1+slot_value inside slots column
Wednesday 48*2+slot_value inside slots column
Thursday  48*3+slot_value inside slots column
Friday    48*4+slot_value inside slots column
Saturday  48*5+slot_value inside slots column
Sunday    48*6+slot_value inside slots column
```

I would like the final output to look like this
[Final output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1cnr.png)

I have tried using `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).day_name()` but unable to access the multiple list values inside the date column

Also tried iterating row wise, but nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly you need to remove null or NA or NAN values and check proper way of list formats for the date strings and slot values, Below
> code will work but can optimze more. Just added for three days you
> listed you can update the code as per your requirements. get days list
> by value_counts and work on it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import calendar
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'date':[['2022-01-12'],np.nan,['2022-02-26','2022-02-19'],np.nan,['2022-02-20','2022-02-27']],'slots':[[[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]],np.nan,[[14, 15, 16, 17], [14, 15, 16, 17,18]],np.nan,[[14, 15, 16, 17], [14, 15, 16, 17,18]]]})
    
df.isna().sum()
df=df.dropna(how='any')
df=df.explode(['date','slots'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['date_name']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).day_name()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
def func_sun(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
      l = [y +(48*6) for y in x]
      print(l)
      return l

def func_sat(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
      sat = [y +(48*5) for y in x]
      print(sat)
      return sat

def func_fry(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
      fri = [y +(48*4) for y in x]
      print(fri)
      return fri

def func_thurs(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
      thurs = [y +(48*3) for y in x]
      print(thurs)
      return thurs

def func_wed(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
      wed = [y +(48*2) for y in x]
      print(wed)
      return wed

def func_tue(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
      tue = [y +(48*1) for y in x]
      print(tue)
          return tue
    
    df['final_list']=''
    
    df.loc[df[df['date_name'] == 'Wednesday']['slots'].index.values,['final_list']]= df[df['date_name'] == 'Wednesday']['slots'].apply(lambda wed: func_wed(wed))
    df.loc[df[df['date_name'] == 'Saturday']['slots'].index.values,['final_list']]= df[df['date_name'] == 'Saturday']['slots'].apply(lambda sat: func_sat(sat))
    df.loc[df[df['date_name'] == 'Sunday']['slots'].index.values,['final_list']] = df[df['date_name'] == 'Sunday']['slots'].apply(lambda x: func_sun(x))
    
    df
    
    df1 = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    
    df1
```

Comment: Thanks, @GANGABABU MANNAM. This did help by making a few tweaks.